# Am I being scammed from Forex-Billionaires.com?

Tags: private-key

Has anyone used Forex-Billionaires.com? I invested in BTC and am now trying to get a withdrawal. I gave them my CashApp wallet address but now they are saying I have to let them generate a private key for the funds to be attached. Of course there is a fee to pay. I generated my own private key and Bitcoin wallet and sent the public key. I am reading that you never share your Private key. So I assumed that meant not letting the exchange generate a private key for me as well. Does anyone have any advice for me? Exchange is saying that it’s an empty key and they have to generate it in order to add the funds from the trade account. Does this sound right?  Read that the private key is created first and wallet created from the key. So that is why I generated my own. I appreciate any help because I think I might be getting scammed.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a scam.

Comment: You have definitely been scammed. Your money is gone and you will not be able to recover it. You should report the fraud to police but not expect them to get your money back for you. You will be contacted by more scammers now, pretending to be able to help you. They will trick you out of more money.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I thought that was the case.